# Creating Content Type using Schema.xml

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server

I am trying to create a content type from a schema.xml but the fields are not getting created, any ideas?

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101001CC4D99118BEC246AB8D5DF12A34B61F0101" Name="License" Group="Smile" Version="3">
    <Folder TargetName="_cts/License" />
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" Customization="">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" Name="ContentTypeId" />
        </FieldRefs>
        <DisplayPattern>
          <MapToContentType>
            <Column Name="ContentTypeId" />
          </MapToContentType>
        </DisplayPattern>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552}" Name="SelectFilename" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="SelectFilename" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Select" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" AuthoringInfo="(web part connection)" HeaderImage="blank.gif" Sortable="FALSE" Customization="">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" Name="ID" />
        </FieldRefs>
        <DisplayPattern>
          <IfEqual>
            <Expr1>
              <GetVar Name="SelectedID" />
            </Expr1>
            <Expr2>
              <Column Name="ID" />
            </Expr2>
            <Then>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<img align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/15/images/rbsel.gif?rev=23" alt="]]></HTML>
              <HTML>Selected</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
            </Then>
            <Else>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<a href="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML>
              <GetVar Name="View" />
              <HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML>
              <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
                <Column Name="ID" />
              </ScriptQuote>
              <HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" onclick="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML>
              <GetVar Name="View" />
              <HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML>
              <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
                <Column Name="ID" />
              </ScriptQuote>
              <HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/15/images/rbunsel.gif?rev=23"  alt="]]></HTML>
              <HTML>Normal</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
            </Else>
          </IfEqual>
        </DisplayPattern>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FileLeafRef" Group="_Hidden" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE" Type="File" DisplayName="Name" AuthoringInfo="(for use in forms)" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="LeafName" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Required="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" Name="Created" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Created" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Created" StorageTZ="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" Group="_Hidden" Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" Required="FALSE" FromBaseType="TRUE" Customization="" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}" Name="Modified" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Modified" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Modified" StorageTZ="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9}" Name="Modified_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Modified By" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb}" Name="Created_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Created By" Customization="" />
      <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Expires" Description="Enter the date this record will expire." Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" Group="*Operation Smile" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{45a8379e-5d0c-458a-be50-6c2cbf460cb0}" SourceID="{a0c66250-262a-48da-8fe8-ab76ae5e67ea}" StaticName="Expires1" Name="Expires1" Customization="" />
      <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="ExpirationAlertDate" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" Group="*Operation Smile" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{c01f9abd-1571-4f5f-9b4a-34e37f6e6a1b}" SourceID="{a0c66250-262a-48da-8fe8-ab76ae5e67ea}" StaticName="ExpirationAlertDate" Name="ExpirationAlertDate" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{B0227F1A-B179-4D45-855B-A18F03706BCB}" Name="_dlc_Exempt" StaticName="_dlc_Exempt" DisplayName="Exempt from Policy" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" Group="Document and Record Management Columns" Type="ExemptField" Indexed="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" OverwriteInChildScopes="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{74E6AE8A-0E3E-4DCB-BBFF-B5A016D74D64}" Name="_dlc_ExpireDateSaved" StaticName="_dlc_ExpireDateSaved" DisplayName="Original Expiration Date" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" Group="Document and Record Management Columns" Type="DateTime" Indexed="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" OverwriteInChildScopes="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{ACD16FDF-052F-40F7-BB7E-564C269C9FBC}" Name="_dlc_ExpireDate" StaticName="_dlc_ExpireDate" DisplayName="Expiration Date" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" Group="Document and Record Management Columns" Type="DateTime" Indexed="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" OverwriteInChildScopes="TRUE" Customization="">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
        <spe:Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
          <Receiver>
            <Name>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10001</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>101</SequenceNumber>
            <Url>
            </Url>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Policy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate</Class>
            <Data>
            </Data>
            <Filter>
            </Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10002</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>102</SequenceNumber>
            <Url>
            </Url>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Policy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate</Class>
            <Data>
            </Data>
            <Filter>
            </Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10004</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>103</SequenceNumber>
            <Url>
            </Url>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Policy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate</Class>
            <Data>
            </Data>
            <Filter>
            </Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10006</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>104</SequenceNumber>
            <Url>
            </Url>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Policy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate</Class>
            <Data>
            </Data>
            <Filter>
            </Filter>
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10009</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>105</SequenceNumber>
            <Url>
            </Url>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Policy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate</Class>
            <Data>
            </Data>
            <Filter>
            </Filter>
          </Receiver>
        </spe:Receivers>
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="office.server.policy">
        <p:Policy xmlns:p="office.server.policy" id="" local="true">
          <p:Name>Expiring Documents</p:Name>
          <p:Description>
          </p:Description>
          <p:Statement>
          </p:Statement>
          <p:PolicyItems>
            <p:PolicyItem featureId="Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Expiration" staticId="0x0101001CC4D99118BEC246AB8D5DF12A34B61F01|726354630" UniqueId="c324a1a6-bb2d-4e52-b86a-c2b8b79f83cb">
              <p:Name>Retention</p:Name>
              <p:Description>Automatic scheduling of content for processing, and performing a retention action on content that has reached its due date.</p:Description>
              <p:CustomData>
                <Schedules nextStageId="2">
                  <Schedule type="Default">
                    <stages>
                      <data stageId="1">
                        <formula id="Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Expiration.Formula.BuiltIn">
                          <number>0</number>
                          <property>ExpirationAlertDate</property>
                          <propertyId>c01f9abd-1571-4f5f-9b4a-34e37f6e6a1b</propertyId>
                          <period>days</period>
                        </formula>
                        <action type="workflow" id="fb97da3d-4c25-4c1a-8e7d-d9d87a17741b" />
                      </data>
                    </stages>
                  </Schedule>
                </Schedules>
              </p:CustomData>
            </p:PolicyItem>
          </p:PolicyItems>
        </p:Policy>
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>DocumentLibraryForm</Display>
          <Edit>DocumentLibraryForm</Edit>
          <New>DocumentLibraryForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code blocks, before `<ContentType>`, You need to create your custom fields. I guess you are missing that, that is why you are unable to see that fields. Your `Schema.xml` should like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field ID="{00D74D75-B775-4222-967D-D26973B8C5DB}" Name="CustomField" DisplayName="Custom Field" Type="Text"/>  
  <Field ID="{C3CD561C-D714-42DE-8112-C830B4108CEF}" Name="CustomChoiceField" DisplayName="Custom Choice Field" Type="Choice">  
    <CHOICES>  
      <CHOICE>Choice 1</CHOICE>  
      <CHOICE>Choice 2</CHOICE>  
      <CHOICE>Choice 3</CHOICE>  
    </CHOICES>  
  </Field>  
  <!-- Your Content type code blocks here -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0101001CC4D99118BEC246AB8D5DF12A34B61F0101" Name="License" Group="Smile" Version="3">
      .....Your Content type code blocks here....
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Read [this - Create Content Type Using Schema](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-content-type-using-schema/) article for more.

Comment: tried that doesn't work